# Efficiency of bit string instructions, for example as used in radix sort

Tags: c, sorting, optimization, assembly, bit-manipulation

Should I expect that using the specialized x86 bit string instructions will bring a big performance enhancement over using the standard C algorithms for the same functionality? An example of bit string operations would be a radix sort.

I wrote a radix sort algorithm in Java and the in-place version was about 5 times faster than using Arrays.sort on ints, so I am thinking if I write a radix sort using the x86 native instructions (BSF, BSR, BT, BTC, BTS and BTR) it should just crush library sorts.

Is this a reasonable expectation or are these instructions so neglected that multi-line algorithms will be comparable? I have heard that Intel has ignored optimization of CISC instructions so they can be really slow.

Comment: Can we see some code? I'd like to justify myself that BSF can be in the critical path of a sorting algorithm.

Comment: It reasonable only to expect that a non-library algorithm may beat library sorting because of reduced overhead with function pointers (and lack of dynamic allocation of objects). Also it's reasonable to believe that the performance may vary from one sample to another (reversed input, almost sorted, random, 10,100,10M cases).

Comment: A typical radix sort is not in place. It uses a portion of the value from an array as part of an index to an output array. The process loops from least significant portion to most significant portion, while moving data back and forth between two arrays. Normal shift and mask operations are done to get the portions of values, and I don't see how the bit scan instructions would help.

Comment: I don't see how testing for single bits makes a counting sort (as part of a radix sort) particularly useful. You'd only "sort" each element into one of **2** bins each iteration, which I suspect turns it into a quick/merge/heap-sort O(nlogn).